# Initiate List<ChildClass> into List<ParentClass>

Tags: c#

I have troubles with finding the correct words for this question, so I will try to show you with some code what my problem is.

I have a parent class, which looks like this:

```
public class ParentClass {
    public Guid ParentId { get; }
    public int ParentProperty { get; set; }
    public List<ParentClass> ParentList { get; set; }

    public ParentClass() {
        this.ParentId = Guid.NewGuid();
    }
}
```

It is rather simple: It got an ID, a few properties and a List containing elements of itself.

Now I am creating a child class, which looks like this:

```
public class ChildClass : ParentClass {
    public string ChildProperty { get; set; }

    public ChildClass() : base() {
        this.ParentList = new List<ChildClass>();
    }
}
```

This one got one extra property and a constructor, which contains the problem. I can't initiate a List into the declaration of the List.
I can't just do the declaration of the list in the child class, as I need it in the parent class when I am using it.

What is the best way to solve this problem?

Comment: You are asking for a way to add a Father or Mother object to a list of Children.  The C# language does not support incest.

Comment: It might help if you explain the reason *why* you need to do this

Comment: can't you just do `this.ParentList = new List<ParentClass>()`? you could add ChildClass objects anyway

Comment: I am using the parent class in basically every project, in every project there are usually only a few small differences between the parent and what I need, therefore I want to use a parent class and fit the child class to the project @Sayse

Comment: I feel really dumb now @slawekwin

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use an interface that point both classes (`ParentClass` as well as `ChildClass`).

A generic type having a certain type-parameter is a "new" type: So `List<ChildClass>` and `List<ParentClass>` are different types.

Answer (score 1):

I think the easiest way to achieve what you want is to initiate the list with its base type : `List<ParentClass>`

```
public class ChildClass : ParentClass
{
    public string ChildProperty { get; set; }

    public ChildClass() : base() {
        this.ParentList = new List<ParentClass>();
    }

    public void AddSomething()
    {
        // this is ok :
        this.ParentList.Add(new ChildClass());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This could work only if the type `List<T>` were covariant in `T`, also known as "`out T`". However, it is not, and cannot be.

- The type `List<>` allows `Add`, `Insert` and others, and so it is not semantically covariant.
- In C# (as of currently), `class` types cannot be made covariant. That is not supported. Only `interface` and `delegate` types can be made covariant (or contravariant) in their generic parameters.

The closest we get is `IReadOnlyList<out T>` which is covariant, so:

```
IReadOnlyList<ParentClass> parentList = new List<ChildClass>();
```

is allowed. However, it is not helpful *in your case*.

Answer (score 0):

```
 public class ParentClass<TChild>  where TChild : class
    {
        public List<TChild> ParentList { get; set; }
        public Guid ParentId { get; set; }
        public int ParentProperty { get; set; }


        public ParentClass()
        {
            ParentId = Guid.NewGuid();
            ParentList = new List<TChild>();
        }
    }

    public class ChildClass : ParentClass<ChildClass>
    {
        public string ChildProperty { get; set; }

    }
```

Comment: That is a block of code of which I do not have a single idea what it does. You might want to explain it to me

Comment: try to do this var o = new ChildClass(); than you will get fully operational ChildObject with initiated ParentId and constructed ParentList